# How can I retain scroll position using antd table in React

Tags: reactjs, components, row, antd, datasource

I have defined this function

```
  const addRow = useCallback(() => {
    setDataSource((prevRows) => [
      { id: prevRows.length + 1, name: `Item ${prevRows.length + 1}` },
      ...prevRows
    ]);
  }, []);
```

This function adds new row on top of already rendered rows.
In my case use this function to add new row on top of already existed rows in antd.Table.
And i use this function with an interval of 500ms.
Let me define that function too.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(addRow, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Clear the interval on unmount
  }, [addRow]);
```

And now here is my antd.Table component inside App component.

```
      <Table
        className="table-striped-rows"
        rowKey={"id"}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        pagination={false}
      />
```

After server runs a code I wait until rows inside ant table overflows a screen of my browser.
Then I try to read the first row at the bottom of the table.
But now it is quite hard to read that row. Because new rows are being added and old rows keep flowing downward.
So how can I stop that flow in order to read desired rows inside the table?

[Here is url to the complete code of my challenge](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-cdn-l5v9ny?file=/src/App.js)
While runnig this code you may not want to wait until rows overflow the screen by itself.
In that case you can boost the process by clicking **Add Row** button on top of the table.

I really hope someone's help to solve this problem.
Because it's quite important for me.
Thank you in advance!!

I need [something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-brown-xw9xpt?file=/src/App.js). But I have to use antd.Table instead of manually defined ItemList component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check before adding new rows if your component is already bigger than the screen height and then cancel your installed interval.

```js
// you need a ref for the wrapping element
const div = useRef(null);
```

```
// in your top-level element this ref can be used
<div ref={div}>
```

And then you can do something like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (
        div.current &&
        div.current.getBoundingClientRect().height >= window.innerHeight
      ) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      } else {
        addRow();
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Clear the interval on unmount
  }, [addRow]);
```

You can find the adjustment here: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-bash-k79y63?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but this time program completely stops adding new rows. I want a program to keep adding rows while I am reading the desired rows

Comment: [like in this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-brown-xw9xpt?file=/src/App.js). Notice that rows are being added continously while you read any of the items after overflow. Scroll downward after overflow @viktor

Comment: Ahh. So you want to retain the scroll position at the right place basically?

Comment: exactly. I just didn't know another way of how to explain the problem

Comment: Ok. Then I understood the problem now, but I think that might not be easy to fix. Sorry. Tried a little, but found no easy solution. And cannot spend much more time currently.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much for your attention and effort @ViktorLuft